# Re-sizing @page to landscape 4x6

Tags: css

I have a 4x6 piece of paper. I would like it to print landscape. Is there anyway to do this? I've tried different combinations of the code below with no luck. The goal is to get it to work in IE 11.

I also tried adding a rotation to my printable area. also with no luck

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: 6in 4in landscape;
        margin: 0in 0in 0in 0in;
    }
    #printable {
        display: block;
        rotation:90deg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after Googling Rotation it tells you that rotation isn't supported by any browser [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_rotation.asp). I then tried `transform` [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) which seems to work. If someone know of an easier way let me know!

```
@media print {
    @page {
        size: 6in 4in landscape;
        margin: 0in;
    }

    #printable {
        display: block;
        transform:translate(-2.09in,5.65in) rotate(90deg);
        transform-origin: top right;
    }
 }
```